# Python package not importing correctly

Tags: python-module, pypi

I created a python package and then uploaded it to PyPI

https://pypi.org/project/emojicrypt/#description

A link to the github repo:
https://github.com/InputBlackBoxOutput/EmojiCrypt

When I install the module using `pip install emojicrypt`, pip installs the package but when I try to import the module I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'emojicrypt'` error

I looked up the 'site-packages' directory, here is what it looks like

```
C:.
├───Crypto
├───cv2
├───emojicrypt-1.0.0.dist-info
├───numpy
├───numpy-1.20.3.dist-info
├───opencv_python-4.5.2.54.dist-info
├───pip
├───pip-21.1.1.dist-info
├───pkg_resources
├───pycryptodome-3.10.1.dist-info
├───setuptools
├───setuptools-56.0.0.dist-info
└───_distutils_hack
```

I speculate that a directory named 'emojicrypt' should exist here but is missing.

What has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why did it happen?

The find_packges() function in setup.py was unable to find the program files since the directory structure was wrong.

How to fix it?

The program files should be inside a directory with an `__init__.py` file to make the directory behave as a module.